# Hive Approaching Namespace Quota Because of INSERT INTO

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

When I run the following command:

```
hdfs fs -count -q -h -v <user-path>
```

I see the following numbers.

```
   QUOTA       REM_QUOTA     SPACE_QUOTA REM_SPACE_QUOTA    DIR_COUNT   FILE_COUNT       CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
  20.5 K          19.8 K          1000 G         950.5 G           82        7.6 K             13.8 G <user-path>
```

I think the problem lies here. If I run the following query in pyspark, it uses a disproportionate amount of my namespace quota.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE <new-table> SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3 
FROM <old-partitioned-table>
WHERE YEAR='2017' 
AND MONTH='03'
GROUP BY col_1, col_2;
```

It is worth pointing out that the  is partitioned by YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, PART. I'm not sure if because it is stored in so many files, it also copies to many files.

Are there solutions where this INSERT can use less files? Perhaps there is some setting that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Repartition before saving?

Comment: This solves it set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true; It merges the small files produced by the map reduce job